# Creating a secondary tile with background image path from isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

in my app all my images are saved in the IsolatedStorage space.
Can I create some secondary tiles with Uri's that link to my app's Isolated storage?
Is there anyway to do this? I wasn't able to find something.

Thanx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well your images have to be saved under Shared/ShellContent. Read documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28VS.92%29.aspx).

So for example you path to image Tile would be something like this:

```
tileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/background.png", UriKind.Absolute)
```

You have to add "isostore" prefix to load images from isolated store.

Comment: Your MSDN link has rotten.